# Converting all object column dtypes to categorical

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spreadsheet that I imported to Pandas that is all strings. I want to convert all of the columns to categories.
I tested this out with single categories and have no problem, but when I try to do it iteratively, I can't seem to get the dtypes to change.

Mock data:

```
a = [['a', '1.2', '4.2'], ['b', '70', '0.03'], ['x', '5', '0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

# works
pd.Categorical(a['one'])
new_one = pd.Categorical(df['one'])

#doesn't work
df['one'] = pd.Categorical(df['one'])

# also doesn't work if I try to create a new df 
# and populate it with the iterated results

for i in list(df.columns):
    df[i] = pd.Categorical(df[i])
```

Comment: `Categorical`s are still not *really* supported well in pandas. so I think what you're trying to do just doesn't really work yet. This is changing a bit in the upcoming version 0.15, see [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#categoricals-in-series-dataframe)

Comment: Ah. That makes me feel better. I was really starting to bang my head against the wall. Back to R? :-/. Just kidding! There's room for them both.

Answer (score 0):

If use pandas `0.23.0` it is possible by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), read more [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#dataframe-astype-performs-column-wise-conversion-to-categorical):

```
df = df.astype('category')
print (df.dtypes)
one      category
two      category
three    category
dtype: object
```